# Where does udev get the model and vendor strings?

Tags: udev

I am creating a udev rule which simply logs the usb storage devices. I have a usb flash disc with `ID_MODEL_ID==1234` and `ID_VENDOR_ID==abcd`. `udev` shows that this is:

```
ID_MODEL=UDisk
ID_VENDOR=General
```

But I don't get where it gets this information.
According to what I see in `usb.ids` of latest `hwdata`:

```
$ cat /usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids | grep abcd
    abcd  Unknown

$ cat /usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids | grep 1234
    1234  IronLogic RFID Adapter [Z-2 USB]
    1234  Bluetooth Device
    1234  Typhoon Redfun Modem V90 56k
    1234  Flash Drive
    1234  Cruzer Mini Flash Drive
    1234  USB to ATAPI
    1234  BACKPACK
    1234  Storage Device
    1234  Fastrack Xtend FXT001 Modem
1234  Brain Actuated Technologies
    1234  PDS6062T Oscilloscope
    1234  ATAPI Bridge
    1234  Prototype Reader/Writer
```

My goal is to simply log `ID_VENDOR_ID` and `ID_MODEL_ID` instead of strings `ID_VENDOR` and `ID_MODEL` and to get these strings later when I need by looking up the `hwdata`'s usb.ids file. It seems to me that `udev` gets these strings from somewhere else but where?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nowhere from. I have found out that `UDisk` is not a real model name, it is just a [`hard drive in USB form`](http://www.getusb.info/whats-the-difference-between-usb-and-udisk/), nothing more or less. The same, the vendor id is `Unknown` and it is just printed as `General` (this is my guess already). So it is correct it seems just to lookup the `usb.ids` file.

`lsusb` does not show this information aswell, so probably there is no any other way to lookup this information and this information is not stored inside the usb device itself along with vendor and model ids.

Comment: `udev` has its own databases (because of NIH syndrome), but I doubt they are very comprehensive. `udisk` is also a desktop component that manages storage devices, so this looks like a generic fallback value. Logging the numeric values is definitely the right thing to do.